# Logout with Spring Security and Keycloak OpenID Connect doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-security, keycloak, openid-connect

I am maintaining this application which is set up with:

- an AngularJS front end
- a Spring back end (with Spring Security, configured as per [the Keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_spring_security_adapter)) running on Tomcat
- Keycloak as single sign-on solution using OpenID Connect.

The Implicit Flow is implemented like this:

- The user navigates to the web app in their browser
- The AngularJS web app checks if a (non-expired) JWT token is present in the Session Storage
- If not, it redirects to Keycloak to request a `token`
- Keycloak authenticates the user and redirects back to the webapp with the token
- The web app stores the token in the Session Storage
- Any request the web app makes to the back end API, it inserts the header `Authorization: Bearer <token>`

So far, so good. However, I noticed that logging out does not work as expected:

- The user clicks the logout button in the web app
- The web app deletes the token from the Session Storage
- The web app redirects to the Keycloak logout endpoint
- The user accesses the back end API directly and succeeds!

The reason is that a `JSESSIONID` cookie is stored and this also authorizes the user to access the API.

My questions:

- Why is a `JSESSIONID` cookie being created? Is it default behaviour of Spring Security? Or did I misconfigure something?
- How should I fix the logout issue? Make sure a `JSESSIONID` cookie is never created? Or implement a logout endpoint in the backend that deletes the session cookie?

NB: I am aware of

- the risks of storing credentials in Session Storage;
- the Implicit Flow being deprecated.

Comment: Did you reach any solutions ?